# Dropcap - :first-letter pseudo class not working as expected in firefox

Tags: css, pseudo-class, drop-cap

I have made a dropcap using `:first-letter pseudo` class it works fine in chrome, IE and edge but it does not works in firefox as expected.

***So what's the problem***

The problem is it's height.

Here is my code:

```css
.dropcap:first-letter {
    font-size: 3em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: .15em;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 3px 22px;
}

.dropcap.dc-bg-primary:first-letter {
    background-color: #1a73e9;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="dropcap dc-bg-primary">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

and here is the link of [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVKwgR)

NOTE: My chrome version is **69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)** and my firefox version is **62.0.3 (32-bit)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Target Firefox Directly

You can target Firox directly like this and solve the issue with different styling.

`@-moz-document url-prefix() {/*styles here*/}`

[image]

```css
.dropcap:first-letter {
    font-size: 3em;
    float: left;
    margin-top: .15em;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 3px 22px;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.dropcap:first-letter {
padding: 15px 20px;
}
}

.dropcap.dc-bg-primary:first-letter {
    background-color: #1a73e9;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="dropcap dc-bg-primary">
                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                                                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                                                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                                                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                            </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason of different behavior is a fact that Chrome uses `line-height` value applied to containing element (`p` in your case) while Firefox drops it.

According to W3C specifications there is nothing wrong with both implementations since point [7.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#application-in-css) of CSS selectors specification tells that:

> To allow UAs to render a typographically correct drop cap or initial cap, the UA may choose a line-height, width and height based on the shape of the letter, unlike for normal elements.

However discussion into [bug 290125](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=290125) shows that Firefox developers plan to change their implementation soon so Firefox will start rendering your example in a same way like other browsers do, but for now you may need to consider some additional fixes like resetting `line-height` for `:first-letter` and add separate `padding` values specifically for Firefox e.g. by using [this](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-48ca6fc2947b7850c571a2f69bdbffbd) hack for detecting it.